# Django TemplateDoesNotExist and BASE_DIRS

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to load a template in django. I created a text file called current_date.html and typed inside the file

```
"It is now {{current_date}}."
```

and put it inside a templates directory

```
C:\Users\reza\env_mysite\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates
```

Then inside the view I wrote below block of code:

```
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template import Context
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404
import datetime

def current_datetime(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    t = get_template('current_datetime.html')
    html = t.render(Context({'current_date':now}))
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

and inside urlpatterns I typed:

```
url(r'^time/$', current_datetime)
```

In the settings.py file, inside DIRS in typed:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
```

and next time I typed

```
'DIRS': ['C:\Users\reza\env_mysite\lib\site-
packages\django\contrib\admin\templates']
```

but in both scenarios I received TemplateDoesNotExist error with below details

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/time/

Django Version: 1.11.2
Python Version: 3.6.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']

Template loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:
    * django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Users\reza\templates\current_datetime.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\reza\env_mysite\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\current_datetime.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\reza\env_mysite\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\current_datetime.html (Source does not exist)
```

Could you please let me know what is wrong with my codes

Answer (score 2):

You should absolutely not be putting your own templates inside any of Django's directories. Your code should be completely separate.

You should create your own `templates` directory inside your project and put your template in there; then your first attempt, `os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')`, would work.

Comment: which one is the project directory env_mysite or mysite? I have both folders

Comment: urls, settings and views are in mysite and include, lib, scripts are in env_mysite

Comment: both of them are in Users/reza

Comment: As an aside, it looks like you need to add `reza` (the name of your application) to the list of INSTALLED_APPLICATIONS in your django settings file.

Answer (score 0):

You said that you placed this new template, `current_date.html` in the `C:\Users\reza\env_mysite\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates` directory. That is part of the Django package, and should contain two directories, `admin/`, and `registration/`. Is it possible that you placed your new template *inside of* one of those inner folders, like the `admin/` folder?

If so, then you should update the call to `get_template()` in your view so that it looks like this:

```
def current_datetime(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    t = get_template('admin/current_datetime.html') # note updated path
    html = t.render(Context({'current_date':now}))
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

Note that you're not conforming to best practices here, but that's a separate issue really. A couple suggestions would be to shift this new template into your own application's `templates/` directory (it's generally not a good idea to make modifications to the installed packages), and you should also use [`django.shortcuts.render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#render), which reduces the amount of code you have to write/manage:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def current_datetime(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    return render(request, 'admin/current_datetime.html', {'current_date':now})
```

Comment: I put it inside templates not admin or registration. Inside the file I also typed It is now {{current_date}}. without double quotes

Comment: I used notepad for text file. Is that fine?

Comment: What happens if you set that template path to a file that definitely exists, like "admin/base.html"? (notepade should be ok)

Comment: I tired different folders none of them worked. I am not sure what I should put inside DIRS. Is it os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates') or the html file path?

Comment: Sorry man, I think you've just muddled too many things up here, and I won't be able to help you sort them out. Have you tried starting a new Django project to see if it works at all? Maybe you could work your way backwards from something that works.